# Scene2d: How to place a widget at the bottom of the screen and another one at the top?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, libgdx, scene2d

I want to have a [ScrollPane](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html) with two [Labels](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html)  above a [Button](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) which **always** stays at the bottom of the screen. This is working fine if there is so much text inside these labels, that scrolling is possible. But if there are only a few lines, the button stays right under the ScrollPane and so it may happen that the Button is at the middle of the screen.

Here's my code:

```
    Table container = new Table();
    container.setFillParent(true);
    container.top();

    Table table = new Table();

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setOverscroll(false, false);

    Label label1 = new Label(text1, labelStyle);

    Label label2 = new Label(text2, labelStyle);
    label2.setWrap(true);

    Button button = new Button(buttonStyle);

    table.add(label1).pad(paddingText);
    table.row();
    table.add(label2).pad(0, paddingText, 0, paddingText).width(stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth() - 2 * paddingText);

    container.add(scrollPane);
    container.row();
    container.add(button).pad(paddingButton).bottom();

    stage.addActor(container);
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `Cell#fill` and `Cell#expand` methods: `table.add(...).fillY().expandY();`

Comment: Works perfect! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Cell#fill and Cell#expand methods:

```
table.add(...).fillY().expandY();
```

This will expand the cell on the Y-Axis and fill it.